# Windows Azure - create subscription programmatically

Tags: azure

Is there a way to create a new subscription and add it to a Windows Azure account programmatically?

The goal is to have a web application where users can register and deploy a set of virtual machines (automatically). The web application should use an existing Windows Azure account and add a new subscription to it, which is then used to deploy the machines for the new user.

Any suggestions for implementing this, without having to manually access the management portal and add a new subscription?

Comment: Unfortunately the answers are right - you can't create a subscription programmatically. If you end up using a single subscription, you need to be aware (if you aren't already) that there are limits on the number of cloud services, VMs, cores per subscription. For example - 2000 cores per subscription.

Comment: Feature request: [Enable programmatic creation of subscriptions](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/6265297-enable-programmatic-creation-of-subscriptions)

Answer (score 1):

There's no REST API or any other programmatic method for creating a subscription. Subscriptions have related security checks, specific plans, payment methods, etc. This part must be done via the [windowsazure.com](http://www.windowsazure.com) portal.

Once this is complete, though, you can programmatically create cloud services, deploy VMs (based on either gallery images or your own custom images), and pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions must be created via the portal. Everything else can be done via the [Azure Service Management apis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Azure has it planned but I struggle to find any further details on this. The admin that responded mentions as planned on Jun 2016. No further details.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/13117482-api-for-creating-accounts-and-subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Partner Center has API to create Azure Subscriptions:

```
IAggregatePartner partnerOperations;
string customerId;
string offerId;

var order = new Order()
{
    ReferenceCustomerId = customerId,
    LineItems = new List<OrderLineItem>()
    {
        new OrderLineItem()
        {
            OfferId = offerId,
            FriendlyName = "new offer purchase",
            Quantity = 5
        }
    }
};

var createdOrder = partnerOperations.Customers.ById(customerId).Orders.Create(order);
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/integration/manage-customers/add-subscriptions#c

More info about Partner Center Program here: https://partnercenter.microsoft.com/en-us/partner/home

Answer (score 0):

At the time this was comment was made, creating subscriptions are supported as a preview API/Powershell/CLI for Enterprise Agreements (EA)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest

```
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/747ddfe5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Subscription/createSubscription?api-version=2018-03-01-preview

{
  "displayName": "Dev Team Subscription",
  "offerType": "MS-AZR-0017P",
  "owners": [
    {
      "objectId": "<userObjectId>"
    },
    {
      "objectId": "<servicePrincipalObjectId>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: there is a limitation of 50 subscriptions/account created using the API